# Internet Explorer 11 (IE 11) deletes backslashs and changes attrtibute order using parseFromString in DOMParser

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer-11, domparser

I am trying to manipulate some Word XML Code and therefore want to build a XML DOM with `var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml')`. Due to I am implementing a Word AddIn, I have to use IE11..
Are there some polyfills or custom xml parser available to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance :)

https://codepen.io/Dome4/pen/LBONdv

Comment: Please explain why the order of attributes is important.  Please also note that you haven't escaped the backslashes in the large string `xml`, so by the time the DOMParser gets the XML string there aren't any backslashes for it to remove.  Please also note that this is the expected behaviour in all browsers, not just IE11.

Comment: You're quite right, the order of the attributes doesn't play any role, that's my fault. The problem with the DOMParser in IE 11 in the Word context is the change of namespaces to different attributes... Word cannot handle this changes. My solution is to use https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom in the backend and everything works fine :)

Thanks for your help!